# Index of a table row when found by predicate

Tags: atata

I'm finding a TableRow with a predicate thus:

`Table.Rows[r => r.name == "blablabla"]`

Is there any way to get the index of the row it finds as an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexOf` method should work for that:

```
int index = Table.Rows.IndexOf(r => r.name == "blablabla");
```

To assert index:

```
Table.Rows.IndexOf(r => r.name == "blablabla").Should.Be(2);
```